# Image specification needed for React-360 pano cubemap

Tags: react-360

When I try to render my cubemap in react360 I am getting a pitchblack viewport in the browser and in the console I have : WebGL-0x20848408300 texture bound to texture unit is not renderable, it may be none power of 2 and have incompatible texture filtering...

I have resized my images at 512 by 512 so im guessing it is the filtering that is the issue...  How should my images be filterd to be used in the pano cubemap?  I cannot find any information anywhere on this.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed.  One of the images was the wrong size